# Scikit-learn - How to use Cross Validation correctly

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation, supervised-learning

I am working on a program where I have some data (labeled and unlabeled) and 2 different groups ("artritis" and "fibro"). I would like to obtain the classifier's accuracy and then classify the unlabeled data. My problem is that I am testing it with 2 classifiers (LDA and QDA). With the first one I obtain an accuracy of 81% and when I classify the unlabeled data  (39 objects) it classifies everything correctly. However, when I use QDA I obtain an accuracy of 93,74% and when it classifies the unlabeled data (the same 39 objects) it labels 3 of them with the wrong group. Can someone help me to find my errors?

**My code:**

```
    #"listaTrain" has a list of dictionaries which are the labeled data and will be used for
    # training and Cross-Validation
    #"listaLabels" has a list of the train labels
    #"listaClasificar" has a list of dictionaries which are the unlabeled data 
    # which I want to label
    #"clasificador" is my classifier 

    X=vec.fit_transform(listaTrain) #I transform the dictionaries to 
    #a format that sklearn can use
    X=preprocessing.scale(X.toarray()) #I scale the values

    clasificador.fit(X, listaLabels) #I train the classifier with the train data and
    # the train labels
    n_samples = X.shape[0]
    cv = cross_validation.ShuffleSplit(n_samples, n_iter=300, test_size=0.6, random_state=4)
    #I make Cross-Validation dividing the X's data (40% for training and 60% for testing)
    scores = cross_validation.cross_val_score(clasificador, X, listaLabels,v=cv)
    #I obtain the Cross-validation accuracy
    scores.mean() #I obtain the accuracy mean (here is where i obtain 81% and 93%)

    testX=vec.transform(listaClasificar) #I transform the dictionaries to a 
    #format that sklearn can use
    testX=preprocessing.scale(testX.toarray()) #I scale the values

    predicted=clasificador.predict(testX) #I predict the labels of the unlabeled data
```

Comment: Your code looks fine. This is more likely something to do with the structure of your data. Just because the QDA model has a better accuracy on the labeled data doesn't necessarily mean that it will perform better on the unlabeled data.

Comment: But if LDA has an accuracy of 81% and QDA has 93% shouldn't the LDA fail in the clasification of the data instead of the QDA (borth classifying the same data)?

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing how your unlabeled data compares to your labeled data. Are all the unlabeled data supposed to fall into the same group?

Comment: No, from the 39 unlabeled data, the first 25 should be classified as "artriticos" and the last 14 as "fibro"